# Salesforce.com mobile simulators

Tags: mobile

I am planning to check out Salesforce.com mobile for the different mobile platforms. I would like to know if I can make use of the simulators for the respective platforms.

Please let me know if you have tried setting up salesforce.com mobile in simulators and faced any issues or want to share your suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't - at least officially.

1) You can not install apps from App Store on an iOS simulator - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611146/can-i-install-the-app-store-in-an-ios-simulator

2) Android - This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154222/google-play-on-android-4-0-emulator but this is more of a hack

Alternatively, if you can find the APK somehow - you can always load it using adb on to your Android emulator

3) BlackBerry - Similarly if you manage to get the cod and jad files, you can load them on the BlackBerry emulator.

I would still recommend trying it on an actual device as certain features like calling etc. will not be available on the simulator. If you do not have a device, you can always try and get a remote device from a service such as DeviceAnywhere.